# Solr: Searching a term in multiple, indexed fields and returning top 'N' hits from each search field

Tags: solr, autocomplete

I have two indexed fields in my **Solr schema**

1. Employee Name
2. Manager Name

Which are plain strings.

*my Question is:* Given a search term, I want to display top 5 suggested completions from Manager Names and the next 5 from Employee Names.

I can use copy fields, but sometimes I get all top 10 results from Employee Names.

I have a hunch that boosting can help me.. but could not figure out how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boost can't help you control the results and distribute 5 each in the top 10 results.
Probably you can check on [Field Collapsing](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing), where you can group per role (Manager and Name) and limit 5 results for the group.
So you would have 2 groups returned back to you with 5 results each.

Comment: cool. Grouping works from the browser. But how can i do multiple group.field (group.field=emp_field & group.field=mgr_field) using solrj?

Comment: you can do it on a single field. You can combine the fields into one.